# Why do we use JMS in particular?

Tags: java, jms

Why do we use JMS when you can create queue manually, or do the async function manually? What does JMS specifically do which we can't achieve through normal code?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do we use JMS in particular?

Because:

- it is better use of developer time to use JMS than to reinvent the wheel "manually", and
- when you have finished there is less (probably inferior) custom code that the next guy has to maintain.

On the other hand, if your applications requirements are simple enough that intra-JVM queues and the java.util / java.util.concurrent queuing classes are *all* that you need, then you probably shouldn't use JMS.

---

> What does JMS specifically do which we can't achieve through normal code?

Technically / theoretically nothing, but see above.

Answer (score 1):

JMS is analagous to JDBC.  It allows you to write code that uses messaging frameworks without directly using proprietary classes.  Because your code uses the common classes/interfaces, it is possible to change messaging implementations without changing all of your code.  If you want to change from MQ to HornetQ, or change application containers in which your application code executes, you don't have to change the majority of the code publishing / consuming messages.

Answer (score 0):

- It simplify coding (ie, you don't need to develop a database engine,
  when you CAN do it manually)
- It separate codes from environment setting (ie, you don't need to recompile/deploy when you environment  changes --just configure it)
- Reliability, Sequential messaging, QoS, Priority, etc, etc.